# Pandas merge dataframes on ip-address by range

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, merge, left-join, ip-address

I have two dataframes containing some ip information that I'd like to merge (equivalent to a left join in sql). The dataframes have the following fields:

```
df1: ["company","ip","actions"]  
df2: ["ip_range_start","ip_range_end","country","state","city"]
```

The result dataframe should have the headers: `["company","ip","actions","country","state","city"]`. The problem here is my merge criteria. df1 contains a single ip that I'd like to use to pull the country, state, and city information from df2.

This single ip **will** fall into one of the ranges specified by df2's `"ip_range_start"` and `"ip_range_end"` fields. I'm not sure how to accomplish this as a normal merge/join will obviously not do the trick as there's no matching values between df1 and df2.

My question seems very similar to this one, but different enough to warrant a separate question: [Pandas: how to merge two dataframes on offset dates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30489733/pandas-how-to-merge-two-dataframes-on-offset-dates)

Comment: Care to share some of the data?

Comment: You could divide the IP's hierarchical numbers  to separate fields. That may simplify the solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

assume you have the following data frames:

```
In [5]: df1
Out[5]:
  company           ip actions
0   comp1    10.10.1.2    act1
1   comp2   10.10.2.20    act2
2   comp3   10.10.3.50    act3
3   comp4  10.10.4.100    act4

In [6]: df2
Out[6]:
  ip_range_start ip_range_end   country   state   city
0      10.10.2.1  10.10.2.254  country2  state2  city2
1      10.10.3.1  10.10.3.254  country3  state3  city3
2      10.10.4.1  10.10.4.254  country4  state4  city4
```

we can create a vectorized function which will calculate numerical IP representation similar to [int(netaddr.IPAddress('192.0.2.1'))](https://pythonhosted.org/netaddr/tutorial_01.html#numerical-representation):

```
def ip_to_int(ip_ser):
    ips = ip_ser.str.split('.', expand=True).astype(np.int16).values
    mults = np.tile(np.array([24, 16, 8, 0]), len(ip_ser)).reshape(ips.shape)
    return np.sum(np.left_shift(ips, mults), axis=1)
```

let's convert all IPs to their numerical representations:

```
df1['_ip'] = ip_to_int(df1.ip)
df2[['_ip_range_start','_ip_range_end']] = df2.filter(like='ip_range').apply(lambda x: ip_to_int(x))

In [10]: df1
Out[10]:
  company           ip actions        _ip
0   comp1    10.10.1.2    act1  168427778
1   comp2   10.10.2.20    act2  168428052
2   comp3   10.10.3.50    act3  168428338
3   comp4  10.10.4.100    act4  168428644

In [11]: df2
Out[11]:
  ip_range_start ip_range_end   country   state   city  _ip_range_start  _ip_range_end
0      10.10.2.1  10.10.2.254  country2  state2  city2        168428033      168428286
1      10.10.3.1  10.10.3.254  country3  state3  city3        168428289      168428542
2      10.10.4.1  10.10.4.254  country4  state4  city4        168428545      168428798
```

now let's add a new column to the `df1` DF, which will contain an index of the first  **matching** IP interval from the `df2` DF:

```
In [12]: df1['x'] = (df1._ip.apply(lambda x: df2.query('_ip_range_start <= @x <= _ip_range_end')
   ....:                                       .index
   ....:                                       .values)
   ....:                   .apply(lambda x: x[0] if len(x) else -1))

In [14]: df1
Out[14]:
  company           ip actions        _ip  x
0   comp1    10.10.1.2    act1  168427778 -1
1   comp2   10.10.2.20    act2  168428052  0
2   comp3   10.10.3.50    act3  168428338  1
3   comp4  10.10.4.100    act4  168428644  2
```

finally we can merge both DFs:

```
In [15]: (pd.merge(df1.drop('_ip',1),
   ....:           df2.filter(regex=r'^((?!.?ip_range_).*)$'),
   ....:           left_on='x',
   ....:           right_index=True,
   ....:           how='left')
   ....:    .drop('x',1)
   ....: )
Out[15]:
  company           ip actions   country   state   city
0   comp1    10.10.1.2    act1       NaN     NaN    NaN
1   comp2   10.10.2.20    act2  country2  state2  city2
2   comp3   10.10.3.50    act3  country3  state3  city3
3   comp4  10.10.4.100    act4  country4  state4  city4
```

Let's compare the speed of the standard int(IPAddress) to our function (we will use 4M rows DF for the comparison):

```
In [21]: big = pd.concat([df1.ip] * 10**6, ignore_index=True)

In [22]: big.shape
Out[22]: (4000000,)

In [23]: big.head(10)
Out[23]:
0      10.10.1.2
1     10.10.2.20
2     10.10.3.50
3    10.10.4.100
4      10.10.1.2
5     10.10.2.20
6     10.10.3.50
7    10.10.4.100
8      10.10.1.2
9     10.10.2.20
Name: ip, dtype: object

In [24]: %timeit
%timeit  %%timeit

In [24]: %timeit big.apply(lambda x: int(IPAddress(x)))
1 loop, best of 3: 1min 3s per loop

In [25]: %timeit ip_to_int(big)
1 loop, best of 3: 25.4 s per loop
```

Conclusion: our function is approx. 2.5 times faster

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to use R instead of Python, I've written an [ipaddress](https://davidchall.github.io/ipaddress/) package which can solve this problem.

Using the same data from MaxU's answer:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ipaddress)
library(fuzzyjoin)

addr <- tibble(
  company = c("comp1", "comp2", "comp3", "comp4"),
  ip = ip_address(c("10.10.1.2", "10.10.2.20", "10.10.3.50", "10.10.4.100")),
  actions = c("act1", "act2", "act3", "act4")
)
nets <- tibble(
  ip_range_start = ip_address(c("10.10.2.1", "10.10.3.1", "10.10.4.1")),
  ip_range_end = ip_address(c("10.10.2.254", "10.10.3.254", "10.10.4.254")),
  country = c("country2", "country3", "country4"),
  state = c("state2", "state3", "state4"),
  city = c("city2", "city3", "city4")
)

nets <- nets %>%
  mutate(network = common_network(ip_range_start, ip_range_end)) %>%
  select(network, country, state, city)

fuzzy_left_join(addr, nets, c("ip" = "network"), is_within)
#> # A tibble: 4 x 7
#>   company          ip actions      network country  state  city 
#>   <chr>     <ip_addr> <chr>     <ip_netwk> <chr>    <chr>  <chr>
#> 1 comp1     10.10.1.2 act1              NA <NA>     <NA>   <NA> 
#> 2 comp2    10.10.2.20 act2    10.10.2.0/24 country2 state2 city2
#> 3 comp3    10.10.3.50 act3    10.10.3.0/24 country3 state3 city3
#> 4 comp4   10.10.4.100 act4    10.10.4.0/24 country4 state4 city4
```

Using the same benchmark of 4 million addresses, network membership checks are completed in 3.25 seconds.

```r
big <- tibble(ip = rep(addr$ip, 1e6))
big
#> # A tibble: 4,000,000 x 1
#>             ip
#>      <ip_addr>
#>  1   10.10.1.2
#>  2  10.10.2.20
#>  3  10.10.3.50
#>  4 10.10.4.100
#>  5   10.10.1.2
#>  6  10.10.2.20
#>  7  10.10.3.50
#>  8 10.10.4.100
#>  9   10.10.1.2
#> 10  10.10.2.20
#> # … with 3,999,990 more rows
bench::mark(fuzzy_left_join(big, nets, c("ip" = "network"), is_within))$median
#> [1] 3.25s
```