# Combine two pandas DataFrames where the date fields are within two months of each other

Tags: python, date, pandas, dataframe, merge

I need to combine 2 pandas dataframes where df1.date is within 2 months previous of df2. I then want to calculate how many traders had traded the same stock during that period and count the total shares purchased.

I have tried using the approach listed below, but found it far to complicated. I believe there would be a smarter/simpler solution.

[Pandas: how to merge two dataframes on offset dates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30489733/pandas-how-to-merge-two-dataframes-on-offset-dates)

A sample dataset is below:

DF1 (team_1):

```
date        shares  symbol  trader
31/12/2013  154     FDX     Max
30/06/2016  2367    GOOGL   Max
21/07/2015  293     ORCL    Max
18/07/2015  304     ORCL    Sam
```

DF2 (team_2):

```
date        shares  symbol  trader
23/08/2015  345     ORCL    John
04/07/2014  567     FB      John
06/12/2013  221     ACER    Sally
31/11/2012  889     HP      John
05/06/2010  445     ABBV    Kate
```

Required output:

```
date        shares  symbol  trader  team_2_traders  team_2_shares_bought
23/08/2015  345     ORCL    John    2               597
04/07/2014  567     FB      John    0               0
06/12/2013  221     ACER    Sally   0               0
31/11/2012  889     HP      John    0               0
05/06/2010  445     ABBV    Kate    0               0
```

This adds 2 new columns...
'team_2_traders' = count of how many traders from team_1 traded the same stock during the previous 2 months from the date listed on DF2.
'team_2_shares_bought' = count of the total shares purchased by team_1 during the previous 2 months from the date listed on DF2.

If anyone is willing to give this a crack, please use the snippet below to setup the dataframes. Please keep in mind the actual dataset contains millions of rows and 6,000 company stocks.

```
team_1 = {'symbol':['FDX','GOOGL','ORCL','ORCL'], 
          'date':['31/12/2013','30/06/2016','21/07/2015','18/07/2015'], 
          'shares':[154,2367,293,304],
          'trader':['Max','Max','Max','Sam']}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(team_1)

team_2 = {'symbol':['ORCL','FB','ACER','HP','ABBV'],
          'date':['23/08/2015','04/07/2014','06/12/2013','31/11/2012','05/06/2010'],
          'shares':[345,567,221,889,445],
          'trader':['John','John','Sally','John','Kate']}

df2 = pd.DataFrame(team_2)
```

Appreciate the help - thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check my solution.

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import MonthEnd

df_ = df2.merge(df1, on=['symbol'])
df_['date_x'] = pd.to_datetime(df_['date_x'])
df_['date_y'] = pd.to_datetime(df_['date_y'])

df_2m = df_[df_['date_x'] < df_['date_y'] + MonthEnd(2)] \
        .loc[:, ['date_y', 'shares_y', 'symbol', 'trader_y']] \
        .groupby('symbol')

df1_ = pd.concat([df_2m['shares_y'].sum(), df_2m['trader_y'].count()], axis=1)

print(df1_)

        shares_y  trader_y
symbol                    
ORCL         597         2

print(df2.merge(df1_.reset_index(), on='symbol', how='left').fillna(0))

         date  shares symbol trader  shares_y  trader_y
0  23/08/2015     345   ORCL   John     597.0       2.0
1  04/07/2014     567     FB   John       0.0       0.0
2  06/12/2013     221   ACER  Sally       0.0       0.0
3  30/11/2012     889     HP   John       0.0       0.0
4  05/06/2010     445   ABBV   Kate       0.0       0.0
```

Comment: thanks but your solution does not include the within date range lookup that is required.

Comment: Oh I missed the constraint, please check again. I updated the code.

Comment: that works well, thank you! I'll try it on the big dataset later. Cheers!