# Merging dataframes based on date range

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have two pandas dataframes: one (`df1`) with three columns (`StartDate`, `EndDate`, and `ID`) and a second (`df2`) with a Date. I want to merge `df1` and `df2` based on df2.Date between `df1.StartDate` and `df2.EndDate`.

Each date range in `df1` is unique and doesn't overlap with any of the other rows in the dataframe.

Dates are formatted `YYYY-MM-DD`.

Comment: You'll have to define a func to perform the lookup, `merge` will not perform the match for you as it requires exact matches on value rather than between ranges

Comment: See related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21367485/merge-pandas-dataframes-based-on-irregular-time-intervals?rq=1

Answer (score 18):

Just to provide an alternative way using `np.piecewise`. The performance is even faster than `np.searchedsort`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# data
# ====================================
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'StartDate': pd.date_range('2010-01-01', periods=9, freq='5D'), 'EndDate': pd.date_range('2010-01-04', periods=9, freq='5D'), 'ID': np.arange(1, 10, 1)})

df2 = pd.DataFrame(dict(values=np.random.randn(50), date_time=pd.date_range('2010-01-01', periods=50, freq='D')))

df1.StartDate

Out[139]: 
0   2010-01-01
1   2010-01-06
2   2010-01-11
3   2010-01-16
4   2010-01-21
5   2010-01-26
6   2010-01-31
7   2010-02-05
8   2010-02-10
Name: StartDate, dtype: datetime64[ns]

df2.date_time

Out[140]: 
0    2010-01-01
1    2010-01-02
2    2010-01-03
3    2010-01-04
4    2010-01-05
5    2010-01-06
6    2010-01-07
7    2010-01-08
8    2010-01-09
9    2010-01-10
        ...    
40   2010-02-10
41   2010-02-11
42   2010-02-12
43   2010-02-13
44   2010-02-14
45   2010-02-15
46   2010-02-16
47   2010-02-17
48   2010-02-18
49   2010-02-19
Name: date_time, dtype: datetime64[ns]


df2['ID_matched'] = np.piecewise(np.zeros(len(df2)), [(df2.date_time.values >= start_date)&(df2.date_time.values <= end_date) for start_date, end_date in zip(df1.StartDate.values, df1.EndDate.values)], df1.ID.values)


Out[143]: 
    date_time  values  ID_matched
0  2010-01-01 -0.2240           1
1  2010-01-02 -0.4202           1
2  2010-01-03  0.9998           1
3  2010-01-04  0.4310           1
4  2010-01-05 -0.6509           0
5  2010-01-06 -1.4987           2
6  2010-01-07 -1.2306           2
7  2010-01-08  0.1940           2
8  2010-01-09 -0.9984           2
9  2010-01-10 -0.3676           0
..        ...     ...         ...
40 2010-02-10  0.5242           9
41 2010-02-11  0.3451           9
42 2010-02-12  0.7244           9
43 2010-02-13 -2.0404           9
44 2010-02-14 -1.0798           0
45 2010-02-15 -0.6934           0
46 2010-02-16 -2.3380           0
47 2010-02-17  1.6623           0
48 2010-02-18 -0.2754           0
49 2010-02-19 -0.7466           0

[50 rows x 3 columns]

%timeit df2['ID_matched'] = np.piecewise(np.zeros(len(df2)), [(df2.date_time.values >= start_date)&(df2.date_time.values <= end_date) for start_date, end_date in zip(df1.StartDate.values, df1.EndDate.values)], df1.ID.values)
1000 loops, best of 3: 466 µs per loop
```

Comment: Jianxun, thank you for the answer. Is there a way to do this with `datetime64` Series in pandas DataFrames?

Comment: @NicholasTulach i think pandas will treat datetime as datetime64 as a default behaviour. so it should work on datetime64 series as well. if you see any error, could you please upload your sample datafile via a dropbox sharelink so that i can take a look at what might go wrong.

Comment: @NicholasTulach if you run the above sample code, you can check the dtype of index, it's datetime64.

Comment: When i change the code to use an arbitrary column instead of an index, it gives a ValueError. e.g. `df2['ID_matched'] = np.piecewise(np.zeros(len(df2)), [(df2['date'] >= start_date)&(df2['date'] <= end_date) for start_date, end_date in zip(df1.StartDate.values, df1.EndDate.values)], df1.ID.values)`

Comment: @NicholasTulach I think that's because `df2['date']` is a dataframe column, so it has the index with it. If you use `df2['date'].values`, then the `ValueError` should disappear. I've updated my sample code as well. Please give a look.

Comment: Ah, thank you. I am a total noob when it comes to numpy. :)

Comment: This is a great solution. I can't accept it but I upvoted it.

Comment: Any specific reasons why you wouldn't just use df.index instead of creating the ID column in df1?

Answer (score 2):

Minor correction to @JianxunLi answer. Bit too involved for a comment.

This uses the `len(funclist) == len(condlist) + 1` property of `piecewise` to assign a default value for when there is no match.  Otherwise the default no-match value is zero, which can cause problems...

```
### Data / inits
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'StartDate': pd.date_range('2010-01-01', periods=9, freq='5D'), 'EndDate': pd.date_range('2010-01-04', periods=9, freq='5D'), 'ID': np.arange(1, 10, 1)})
df2 = pd.DataFrame(dict(values=np.random.randn(50), date_time=pd.date_range('2010-01-01', periods=50, freq='D')))

### Processing
valIfNoMatch = np.nan
df2['ID_matched'] = np.piecewise(np.zeros(len(df2)),\
                                     [(df2.date_time.values >= start_date)&(df2.date_time.values < end_date) for start_date, end_date in zip(df1.StartDate.values, df1.EndDate.values)],\
                                     np.append(df1.ID.values, valIfNoMatch))
```

PS. Also corrected the typo testing both `>=` & `<=`; a timestamp on an exact boundary between intervals would return true for two different intervals, which breaks a key assumption of the method.

Answer (score 1):

[conditional_join](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/reference/janitor.functions/janitor.conditional_join.html#janitor.conditional_join) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/) may be helpful in the abstraction/convenience; the function is currently in dev:

```py
# pip install git+https://github.com/pyjanitor-devs/pyjanitor.git
import pandas as pd
import janitor
```

Reusing [jianxun-li](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5014134/jianxun-li)'s data:

```py
np.random.seed(123)

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'StartDate': pd.date_range('2010-01-01', periods=9, freq='5D'), 
                    'EndDate': pd.date_range('2010-01-04', periods=9, freq='5D'), 
                    'ID': np.arange(1, 10, 1)})

df2 = pd.DataFrame(dict(values=np.random.randn(50),
                        date_time=pd.date_range('2010-01-01', periods=50, freq='D')))
```

```py
df2.conditional_join(
      df1, 
      ('date_time', 'StartDate', '>='), 
      ('date_time', 'EndDate', '<=')
   )

        left                 right
      values  date_time  StartDate    EndDate ID
0  -1.085631 2010-01-01 2010-01-01 2010-01-04  1
1   0.997345 2010-01-02 2010-01-01 2010-01-04  1
2   0.282978 2010-01-03 2010-01-01 2010-01-04  1
3  -1.506295 2010-01-04 2010-01-01 2010-01-04  1
4   1.651437 2010-01-06 2010-01-06 2010-01-09  2
5  -2.426679 2010-01-07 2010-01-06 2010-01-09  2
6  -0.428913 2010-01-08 2010-01-06 2010-01-09  2
7   1.265936 2010-01-09 2010-01-06 2010-01-09  2
8  -0.678886 2010-01-11 2010-01-11 2010-01-14  3
9  -0.094709 2010-01-12 2010-01-11 2010-01-14  3
10  1.491390 2010-01-13 2010-01-11 2010-01-14  3
11 -0.638902 2010-01-14 2010-01-11 2010-01-14  3
12 -0.434351 2010-01-16 2010-01-16 2010-01-19  4
13  2.205930 2010-01-17 2010-01-16 2010-01-19  4
14  2.186786 2010-01-18 2010-01-16 2010-01-19  4
15  1.004054 2010-01-19 2010-01-16 2010-01-19  4
16  0.737369 2010-01-21 2010-01-21 2010-01-24  5
17  1.490732 2010-01-22 2010-01-21 2010-01-24  5
18 -0.935834 2010-01-23 2010-01-21 2010-01-24  5
19  1.175829 2010-01-24 2010-01-21 2010-01-24  5
20 -0.637752 2010-01-26 2010-01-26 2010-01-29  6
21  0.907105 2010-01-27 2010-01-26 2010-01-29  6
22 -1.428681 2010-01-28 2010-01-26 2010-01-29  6
23 -0.140069 2010-01-29 2010-01-26 2010-01-29  6
24 -0.255619 2010-01-31 2010-01-31 2010-02-03  7
25 -2.798589 2010-02-01 2010-01-31 2010-02-03  7
26 -1.771533 2010-02-02 2010-01-31 2010-02-03  7
27 -0.699877 2010-02-03 2010-01-31 2010-02-03  7
28 -0.173636 2010-02-05 2010-02-05 2010-02-08  8
29  0.002846 2010-02-06 2010-02-05 2010-02-08  8
30  0.688223 2010-02-07 2010-02-05 2010-02-08  8
31 -0.879536 2010-02-08 2010-02-05 2010-02-08  8
32 -0.805367 2010-02-10 2010-02-10 2010-02-13  9
33 -1.727669 2010-02-11 2010-02-10 2010-02-13  9
34 -0.390900 2010-02-12 2010-02-10 2010-02-13  9
35  0.573806 2010-02-13 2010-02-10 2010-02-13  9
```

Under the hood it uses `np.searchsorted` (binary search).

Note that `pd.IntervalIndex` is a more efficient option, especially when the intervals are not overlapping.