# group by custom time periods

Tags: join, pandas, time, group-by

I have a first table with raw data, with just two columns `time` and `temperature`:

```
                            time  temperature
40953 2015-01-01 12:00:00.493000     88.75951
40954 2015-01-01 12:01:00.494000     88.76033
40955 2015-01-01 12:02:00.495000     88.75979
40956 2015-01-01 12:03:00.480000     88.75938
40957 2015-01-01 12:04:00.496000     88.75944
40958 2015-01-01 12:05:00.497000     88.76046
40959 2015-01-01 12:06:00.560000     88.76008
40960 2015-01-01 12:07:00.498000     88.75940
40961 2015-01-01 12:08:00.484000     88.75938
40962 2015-01-01 12:09:00.484000     88.75933
...
```

then I have a second table with periods of data taking.

```
                     start                stop
run                                           
248523 2015-01-05 16:13:09 2015-01-05 17:42:17
248529 2015-01-05 17:47:03 2015-01-05 18:29:27
248530 2015-01-05 18:30:24 2015-01-05 18:33:24
248531 2015-01-05 18:39:31 2015-01-05 18:40:31
248532 2015-01-05 18:43:57 2015-01-06 09:00:17
...
```

As you can see the the runs are not contiguous: a lot of temperature measurements don't belong to any run. There are much more data than periods.

What I need to do is to compute the average temperature for every run, averaging all the temperature measurements belonging to a run. I guess that the first step to do is to join the two tables, but I am not able to express the predicate "`time` between `start` and `stop`". Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, a similar question about irregular time intervals was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21367485/merge-pandas-dataframes-based-on-irregular-time-intervals).

There's a slow method with a for-loop and a faster method using [np.searchsorted](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html). In your case, I suppose you'd need one extra interval_id category for samples which do not fit into any time interval. Does that work?

Comment: Yes, it similar, but actually I am not sure I need to merge the two tables. I need only the average. I don't care about measurements witch don't fit into any interval

Comment: Once you've tagged each row of the first table with an interval_id, then you can calculate the mean of each bin like this:

df.groupby('interval_id').mean()

(I guess it would probably be a good idea to first delete any rows which do not fit into any time interval.)

Comment: sure, but it doesn't seem to me to be the optimal solution. For example now I am doing the opposite: I loop over the period table and for every period I find the data which match, and I accumulate the data to compute the mean. No join is necessary.