# How to combine records based on date using python connected components?

Tags: python, graph, connected-components

I have a list of records (person_id, start_date, end_date) as follows:

```
person_records = [['1', '08/01/2011', '08/31/2011'],
                 ['1', '09/01/2011', '09/30/2011'],
                 ['1', '11/01/2011', '11/30/2011'],
                 ['1', '12/01/2011', '12/31/2011'],
                 ['1', '01/01/2012', '01/31/2012'],
                 ['1', '03/01/2012', '03/31/2012']]
```

The records for each person are sorted in an ascending order of start_date. The periods are consolidated by combining the records based on the dates and recording  the start_date of the first period as the start date and the end_date of the last period as the end date. BUT, If the time between the end of one period and the start of the next is 32 days or less, we should treat this as continuous period. Otherwise, we treat this as two periods:

```
consolidated_person_records = [['1', '08/01/2011', '09/30/2011'],
                               ['1', '11/01/2011', '03/31/2012']]
```

Is there any way to do this using the python connected components?

Comment: Nice question. How is graph-theory and connected components related though?

Comment: Thanks. Got an idea from here [Pandas combining rows based on dates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33264676/pandas-combining-rows-based-on-dates) but do not know how to implement it without using Pandas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought about your question, and I originally wrote a routine that would map the date intervals into a 1D binary array, where each entry in the array is a day, and consecutive days are consecutive entries. With this data structure, you can perform dilation and erosion to fill in small gaps, thus merging the intervals, and then map the consolidated intervals back into date ranges. Thus we use standard raster connected components logic to solve your problem, as per your idea (a graph-based connected components could work as well...)

This works fine, and I can post the code if you are really interested, but then I wondered what the advantages are of the former apporach over the simple routine of just iterating through the (pre-sorted) date ranges and merging the next into the current if the gap is small.

Here is the code for the simple routine, and it takes about 120 micro seconds to run using the sample data. If you expand the sample data by repeating it 10,000 times, this routine takes about 1 sec on my computer.

When I timed the morphology based solution, it was about 2x slower. It might work better under certain circumstances, but I would suggest we try simple first, and see if there's a real problem that requires a different algorithmic approach.

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
import numpy as np
```

The sample data provided in the question:

```
SAMPLE_DATA = [['1', '08/01/2011', '08/31/2011'],
               ['1', '09/01/2011', '09/30/2011'],
               ['1', '11/01/2011', '11/30/2011'],
               ['1', '12/01/2011', '12/31/2011'],
               ['1', '01/01/2012', '01/31/2012'],
               ['1', '03/01/2012', '03/31/2012'],
               ['2', '11/11/2011', '11/30/2011'],
               ['2', '12/11/2011', '12/31/2011'],
               ['2', '01/11/2014', '01/31/2014'],
               ['2', '03/11/2014', '03/31/2014']]
```

The simple approach:

```
def simple_method(in_data=SAMPLE_DATA, person='1', fill_gap_days=31, printit=False):
    date_format_str = "%m/%d/%Y"
    dat = np.array(in_data)
    dat = dat[dat[:, 0] == person, 1:]  # just this person's data
    # assume date intervals are already sorted by start date
    new_intervals = []
    cur_start = None
    cur_end = None
    gap_days = timedelta(days=fill_gap_days)
    for (s_str, e_str) in dat:
        dt_start = datetime.strptime(s_str, date_format_str)
        dt_end = datetime.strptime(e_str, date_format_str)
        if cur_end is None:
            cur_start = dt_start
            cur_end = dt_end
            continue
        else:
            if cur_end + gap_days >= dt_start:
                # merge, keep existing cur_start, extend cur_end
                cur_end = dt_end
            else:
                # new interval, save previous and reset current to this
                new_intervals.append((cur_start, cur_end))
                cur_start = dt_start
                cur_end = dt_end
    # make sure final interval is saved
    new_intervals.append((cur_start, cur_end))

    if printit:
        print_it(person, new_intervals, date_format_str)

    return new_intervals
```

And here's the simple pretty printing function to print the ranges.

```
def print_it(person, consolidated_ranges, fmt):
    for (s, e) in consolidated_ranges:
        print(person, s.strftime(fmt), e.strftime(fmt))
```

Running in ipython as follows. Note that printing the result can be turned off for timing the computation.

```
In [10]: _ = simple_method(printit=True)
1 08/01/2011 09/30/2011
1 11/01/2011 03/31/2012
```

Running in ipython with %timeit macro:

```
In [8]: %timeit simple_method(in_data=SAMPLE_DATA)
10000 loops, best of 3: 118 µs per loop

In [9]: %timeit simple_method(in_data=SAMPLE_DATA*10000)
1 loops, best of 3: 1.06 s per loop
```

[EDIT 8 Feb 2016: To make a long answer longer...]
As I prefaced in my response, I did create a morphological / 1D connected components version and in my timing it was about 2x slower. But for the sake of completeness, I'll show the morphological method, and maybe others will have insight on if there's a big area for speed-up left somewhere in it.

```
#using same imports as previous code with one more
import calendar as cal

def make_occupancy_array(start_year, end_year):
    """
    Represents the time between the start and end years, inclusively, as a 1-D array
    of 'pixels', where each pixel corresponds to a day. Consecutive days are thus
    mapped to consecutive pixels. We can perform morphology on this 1D array to
    close small gaps between date ranges.
    """
    years_days = [(yr, 366 if cal.isleap(yr) else 365) for yr in range(start_year, end_year+1)]
    YD = np.array(years_days)  # like [ (2011, 365), (2012, 366), ... ] in ndarray form
    total_num_days = YD[:, 1].sum()
    occupancy = np.zeros((total_num_days,), dtype='int')
    return YD, occupancy
```

With the occupancy array to represent the time intervals, we need two functions to map from dates to positions in the array and the inverse.

```
def map_date_to_position(dt, YD):
    """
    Maps the datetime value to a position in the occupancy array
    """
    # the start position is the offset to day 1 in the dt1,year,
    # plus the day of year - 1 for dt1 (day of year is 1-based indexed)
    yr = dt.year
    assert yr in YD[:, 0]  # guard...YD should include all years for this person's dates
    position = YD[YD[:, 0] < yr, 1].sum()  # the sum of the days in year before this year
    position += dt.timetuple().tm_yday - 1
    return position


def map_position_to_date(pos, YD):
    """
    Inverse of map_date_to_position, this maps a position in the
    occupancy array back to a datetime value
    """
    yr_offsets = np.cumsum(YD[:, 1])
    day_offsets = yr_offsets - pos
    idx = np.flatnonzero(day_offsets > 0)[0]
    year = YD[idx, 0]
    day_of_year = pos if idx == 0 else pos - yr_offsets[idx-1]
    # construct datetime as first of year plus day offset in year
    dt = datetime.strptime(str(year), "%Y")
    dt += timedelta(days=int(day_of_year)+1)
    return dt
```

The following function fills the relevant part of the occupancy array given start and end dates (inclusive) and optionally extends the end of the range by a gap-filling margin (like 1-sided dilation).

```
def set_occupancy(dt1, dt2, YD, occupancy, fill_gap_days=0):
    """
    For a date range starting dt1 and ending, inclusively, dt2,
    sets the corresponding 'pixels' in occupancy vector to 1.
    If fill_gap_days > 0, then the end 'pixel' is extended
    (dilated) by this many positions, so that we can fill
    the gaps between intervals that are close to each other.
    """
    pos1 = map_date_to_position(dt1, YD)
    pos2 = map_date_to_position(dt2, YD) + fill_gap_days
    occupancy[pos1:pos2] = 1
```

Once we have the consolidated intervals in the occupancy array, we need to read them back out into date intervals, optionally performing 1-sided erosion if we'd previously done gap filling.

```
def get_occupancy_intervals(OCC, fill_gap_days=0):
    """
    Find the runs in the OCC array corresponding
    to the 'dilated' consecutive positions, and then
    'erode' back to the correct end dates by subtracting
    the fill_gap_days.
    """
    starts = np.flatnonzero(np.diff(OCC) > 0)  # where runs of nonzeros start
    ends = np.flatnonzero(np.diff(OCC) < 0)  # where runs of nonzeros end
    ends -= fill_gap_days  # erode back to original length prior to dilation
    return [(s, e) for (s, e) in zip(starts, ends)]
```

Putting it all together...

```
def morphology_method(in_data=SAMPLE_DATA, person='1', fill_gap_days=31, printit=False):
    date_format_str = "%m/%d/%Y"
    dat = np.array(in_data)
    dat = dat[dat[:, 0] == person, 1:]  # just this person's data

    # for the intervals of this person, get starting and ending years
    # we assume the data is already sorted
    #start_year = datetime.strptime(dat[0, 0], date_format_str)
    #end_year = datetime.strptime(dat[-1, 1], date_format_str)
    start_times = [datetime.strptime(d, date_format_str) for d in dat[:, 0]]
    end_times = [datetime.strptime(d, date_format_str) for d in dat[:, 1]]
    start_year = start_times[0].year
    end_year = end_times[-1].year

    # create the occupancy array, dilated so that each interval
    # is extended by fill_gap_days to 'fill in' the small gaps
    # between intervals
    YD, OCC = make_occupancy_array(start_year, end_year)
    for (s, e) in zip(start_times, end_times):
        set_occupancy(s, e, YD, OCC, fill_gap_days)

    # return the intervals from OCC after having filled gaps,
    # and trim end dates back to original position.
    consolidated_pos = get_occupancy_intervals(OCC, fill_gap_days)

    # map positions back to date-times
    consolidated_ranges = [(map_position_to_date(s, YD), map_position_to_date(e, YD)) for
                           (s, e) in consolidated_pos]

    if printit:
        print_it(person, consolidated_ranges, date_format_str)

    return consolidated_ranges
```

Comment: WOW! Thank you so much for your great answer. Actually I have implemented the simple approach and was just curious to see how the connected components approach works. Thanks for comparing the timing. I would love to see the connected component approach.

Comment: I am new to SO and do not have enough score to up-vote your answer. Sorry about that!

Comment: I updated my answer to show the slower morphological method applied to a 1D raster representing the time intervals. If you think this sufficiently answers the question, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

09/30/2011 + 32 days = 11/01/2011, so your example doesn't work.  You probably meant 31 days or less.

When working with dates in python, you can use datetime and timedelta from the datetime module.  Use strptime and strftime to convert from/to strings like '09/01/2011'.

I prefer to convert everything to datetime's at the beginning, do all the date related processing, then convert back to date strings at the end if needed.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

PERSON_ID = 0
START_DATE = 1
END_DATE = 2

def consolidate(records, maxgap=timedelta(days=31)):
    consolidated = []
    consolidated_start = records[0][START_DATE]
    consolidated_end = records[0][END_DATE]

    for person_id, start_date, end_date in records:

        if start_date <= consolidated_end + maxgap:
            consolidated_end = end_date

        else:
            consolidated.append([person_id, consolidated_start, consolidated_end])
            consolidated_start = start_date
            consolidated_end = end_date

    else:
        consolidated.append([person_id, consolidated_start, consolidated_end])

    return consolidated


fmt = "%m/%d/%Y"

records = [[id, datetime.strptime(start, fmt), datetime.strptime(end, fmt)] for id, start, end in person_records]

records = consolidate(records)

records = [[id, start.strftime(fmt), end.strftime(fmt)] for id, start, end in records]
```

EDIT: Here's a version of `consolidate()` using connected_components:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse.csgraph import connected_components

def consolidate(records, maxgap=32):
    person_id = records[0][0]

    dates = np.array([[rec[1].date(), rec[2].date()] for rec in records], dtype='datetime64')
    start_dates, end_dates = dates.T

    gaps = start_dates[1:] - end_dates[:-1]

    conns = np.diagflat(gaps < np.timedelta64(maxgap, 'D'), 1)

    num_comps, comps = connected_components(conns)

    return [[person_id, 
             min(start_dates[comps==i]).astype(datetime),
             max(end_dates[comps==i]).astype(datetime)
            ] for i in range(num_comps)
           ]
```

Comment: Thanks @RootTwo for your answer. I have implemented mine the same way as yours. I just wanted to see if there is a way ti implement it using connected components.. BTW thank you!

Comment: I am new to SO and do not have enough score to up-vote your answer. Sorry about that!