# Faster way to choose minimum of two column if condition meets else just one

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I need to choose minimum of `'Start_x'` and `'Start_y'` if `['Overlap']=='Overlapped'`  otherwise just `'Start_x'`. I wrote below but it is a **bit slow**. is there a **faster way** to do this?

```
df3['Start'] = df3[['Start_x','Start_y','Overlap']].apply
(
lambda x:x[['Start_x','Start_y']].min() if x['Overlap']=='Overlapped' 
else x['Start_x'], axis=1
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try via `np.where()`:

```
import numpy as np
df['Start_x']=np.where(df['Overlap'].eq('Overlapped'),df[['Start_x','Start_y']].min(axis=1),df['Start_x'])
```

OR

via loc and boolean masking

```
df.loc[df['Overlap'].eq('Overlapped'),'Start_x']=df[['Start_x','Start_y']].min(axis=1)
```