# Merge tuples in a list based on their dates items

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a list of tuples, where the first two items in each tuple are dates and the third one is always some name. I want to check: 1) if any two or more tuples have the name as the third item; 2) if the two dates of the tuple are part of or within the two dates of any other tuple. If 1) and 2) are true then only keep the tuple that has the same name and has the longest time span by its two dates.

I have a example data list below

```
data = [(pd.Timestamp('2017-01-02 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2017-01-21 00:00:00'), 'John'), 
        (pd.Timestamp('2017-01-02 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2017-01-21 00:00:00'), 'John'),
        (pd.Timestamp('2017-01-02 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2017-02-04 00:00:00'), 'Jane'),
        (pd.Timestamp('2017-01-02 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2017-02-04 00:00:00'), 'John'),
        (pd.Timestamp('2017-01-21 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2017-02-04 00:00:00'), 'John'),
       (pd.Timestamp('2017-01-01 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2017-02-10 00:00:00'), 'Jane'),]
```

It should output the list below because the two tuples have dates that cover all the other tuples that have the same name (i.e., "John" or "Jane"):

```
[(Timestamp('2017-01-02 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2017-02-04 00:00:00'), 'John'),
 (Timestamp('2017-01-01 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2017-02-10 00:00:00'), 'Jane')]
```

However, my code as now below

```
names = set([x[2] for x in data])
to_remove = []

for i in range(len(data)):
  for j in range(i+1, len(data)):
    if data[i][2] == data[j][2]:
      if data[i][0] >= data[j][0] and data[i][1] <= data[j][1]:
        to_remove.append(j)
      elif data[j][0] >= data[i][0] and data[j][1] <= data[i][1]:
        to_remove.append(i)

data = [x for i,x in enumerate(data) if i not in set(to_remove)]
```

output the wrong answer:

```
[(Timestamp('2017-01-02 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2017-01-21 00:00:00'), 'John'),
 (Timestamp('2017-01-02 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2017-02-04 00:00:00'), 'Jane'),
 (Timestamp('2017-01-21 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2017-02-04 00:00:00'), 'John')]
```

Comment: Your code recomputes `set(to_remove)` in each loop iteration, making it unneccesarily slow.

Comment: If you run your solution twice (feeding the 1st output as 2nd input), is its final answer correct for the sample input? If not, why not?

Comment: If I run the code twice it still outputs the same answer.

Comment: Why doesn't the 2nd run change anything? Why are all your `if`s false in that case? Try to answer this, you may find a bug in your code.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to exchange the position of `i` and `j` when add index to remove list like below implementation.

```
names = set([x[2] for x in data])
to_remove = []

for i in range(len(data)):
  for j in range(i+1, len(data)):
    if data[i][2] == data[j][2]:
      if data[i][0] >= data[j][0] and data[i][1] <= data[j][1]:
        to_remove.append(i)
      elif data[j][0] >= data[i][0] and data[j][1] <= data[i][1]:
        to_remove.append(j)

data = [x for i,x in enumerate(data) if i not in set(to_remove)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would be tempted to do a slightly more brute force approach and accumulate all the dates by key of name and then find the minimum and maximum.

Given you start with:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = [
    (pd.Timestamp('2017-01-02 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2017-01-21 00:00:00'), 'John'), 
    (pd.Timestamp('2017-01-02 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2017-01-21 00:00:00'), 'John'),
    (pd.Timestamp('2017-01-02 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2017-02-04 00:00:00'), 'Jane'),
    (pd.Timestamp('2017-01-02 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2017-02-04 00:00:00'), 'John'),
    (pd.Timestamp('2017-01-21 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2017-02-04 00:00:00'), 'John'),
    (pd.Timestamp('2017-01-01 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2017-02-10 00:00:00'), 'Jane'),
]
```

Then you might use:

```py
## -------------------
## Accumulate based on name
## -------------------
results = {}
for *dates, name in data:
    results.setdefault(name, []).extend(dates)
## -------------------

## -------------------
## Reshape to get min and max
## -------------------
results = [(min(dates), max(dates), name) for name, dates in results.items()]
## -------------------

for result in results:
    print(result)
```

which should give you:

```
(Timestamp('2017-01-02 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2017-02-04 00:00:00'), 'John')
(Timestamp('2017-01-01 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2017-02-10 00:00:00'), 'Jane')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can slightly adjust @[*jakevdp*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33265606/16120011)'s answer :

```
#pip install scipy
from scipy.sparse.csgraph import connected_components

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["start", "end", "name"])

def reductionFunction(df):    
    start = df["start"].to_numpy()
    end = df["end"].to_numpy()
    
    graph = (start <= end[:, None]) & (end >= start[:, None])
    n_components, indices = connected_components(graph)
      
    return df.groupby(indices).agg({"start": "min", "end": "max"})

out = (list(df.groupby("name", sort=False).apply(reductionFunction)
        .reset_index()[df.columns].itertuples(index=False, name=None)))
```

Output:

```
print(out)

[(Timestamp('2017-01-02 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2017-02-04 00:00:00'), 'John'),
 (Timestamp('2017-01-01 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2017-02-10 00:00:00'), 'Jane')]
```